# Volver a ejecutar una parte del codigo hasta que se cumpla

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas amigos, tengo una duda, el hecho es que soy nuevo en esto de la programación y estoy aprendiendo python 3, me encontre con un problema practicando el codigo de la verda un programa muy basico. Lo que pasa es lo siguiente. Quiero seguir ejecutando el programa hasta que me den una opcion valida. Ya veran mas claro cuando vean el codigo

```
print("Bienvenido, escoja una opcion. \n1)Mostrar el contenido de la 
agenda.\n2)Añadir contacto a agenda.\nUtilize el numero correspondiente para 
seleccionar la accion.")

opcion=int(input(">"))

if opcion==1:

    print("Ha seleccionado la opcion 1.")
    agenda=open("agenda.csv")
    print(agenda.read())
    agenda.close()
elif opcion==2:
    agenda=open("agenda.csv", "a")
    nombre=input("Introduzca el nombre\n>")
    numero=input("Introduzca el numero\n>")
    agenda.write(nombre)
    agenda.write(",")
    agenda.write(numero)
    agenda.write("\n")
    print("Contacto guardado con exito")
    agenda.close()
else:
    print("Ha escogido una opcion invalida, intentelo de nuevo.")
```

Lo que me esta pasando es lo siguiente, si ingresamos una opcion distinta de 1 o 2 pasa al else y termina el programa. Pero como puedo pedir una vez tras otra una opcion valida y cuando me den una que sea realmente valida se ejecute el codigo correcto y termine el porgrama, no como cuando llega al else y termina, mas bien que pregunte tantas veces sea necesario dando el mensaje de error y nuevo valor para la variable opcion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La opción más simple es encerrar el código en un ciclo infinito (`while True`) y romperlo (`break`) cuando se inserte una opción válida:

```
opcion = None
while True:
    opcion=int(input(">"))
    if opcion in (1,2):
        break
    else:
        print("Ha escogido una opcion invalida, intentelo de nuevo.")
```

No obstante, en este tipo de ejercicios lo que se suele hacer es permitir que después de realizar una acción se pueda posteriormente hacer otra cosa sin salir del programa, por ejemplo ver la agenda y después agregar un contacto. Para ello basta con hacer algo como:

```
menu ='''
Escoja una opción:
    1)Mostrar el contenido de la agenda.
    2)Añadir contacto a agenda.
    3)Salir.
Utilize el numero correspondiente para seleccionar la accion.
> '''

print('Bienvenido a la agenda de contactos')

while True:
    opcion=input(menu)

    if opcion=='1':
        print("Ha seleccionado la opcion 1.")
        agenda=open("agenda.csv")
        print(agenda.read())
        agenda.close()

    elif opcion=='2':
        agenda=open("agenda.csv", "a")
        nombre=input("Introduzca el nombre\n>")
        numero=input("Introduzca el numero\n>")
        agenda.write(nombre)
        agenda.write(",")
        agenda.write(numero)
        agenda.write("\n")
        print("Contacto guardado con exito")
        agenda.close()

    elif opcion == '3':
        print('Hasta pronto...')
        break

    else:
        print("Ha escogido una opcion invalida, intentelo de nuevo.")
```

Es solo un ejemplo, se puede mejorar según desees, por ejemplo limpiando la consola/terminal después de cada evento.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo Python3, pero esto deberia funcionar:

```
idf = 10
while idf == 10:
print("Bienvenido, escoja una opcion. \n1)Mostrar el contenido de la 
agenda.\n2)Añadir contacto a agenda.\nUtilize el numero correspondiente para 
seleccionar la accion.")

opcion=int(input(">"))

if opcion==1:

    print("Ha seleccionado la opcion 1.")
    agenda=open("agenda.csv")
    print(agenda.read())
    agenda.close()
elif opcion==2:
    agenda=open("agenda.csv", "a")
    nombre=input("Introduzca el nombre\n>")
    numero=input("Introduzca el numero\n>")
    agenda.write(nombre)
    agenda.write(",")
    agenda.write(numero)
    agenda.write("\n")
    print("Contacto guardado con exito")
    agenda.close()
else:
    print("Ha escogido una opcion invalida, intentelo de nuevo.")
```